# Filter data from file using regexp in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I like to create batch script that will do some task on variables that are extracted from file.

I was try to find some regexp, or more to say multiple regexp as i need few variables.

I read file in bash that have:

`username [mutiple spaces] = User Name [mutiple spaces] <u.name@domain.com>`

What i like to do is:
- Get username: 'username '
- Get Full name: 'User Name'
- Get email: 'u.name@domain.com'

As mentioned above i try to get all that details into multiple (three) variables
What i have for now is:

```
input="svn_usernames.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  #USERNAME=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
  #echo $USERNAME
  echo "$line" | perl -pe '/\s\s+/g and / /g'
done < "$input"
```

Comment: This pattern might help: `([^\s]+)\s+\=\s(\w+ \w+)\s+<([^>]+)>` and then you should be able to use `$1` for username, `$2` for User Name, `$3` for email. I don't know bash well enough to incorporate it into your code.

Comment: OP, has your question been answered by @dvo, or do you want another?

Comment: @RoboMop give him another. My feelings won't be hurt. Especially if you can provide more information :)

Comment: Work perfect! As i have no clue how to accept comment as answer ...

Comment: @user_as_is I don't think you can. But that's okay. If someone wants to take my regex pattern and apply it to bash syntax, that'd be more helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will make some assumptions.

```
1) There WILL be spaces before *AND* after the equals
2) "username" is a login id
3) the user's actual name might have multiple fields - given name, surname, etc.
4) the email is JUST the email inside angle brackets.
```

With those given,

```
input="svn_usernames.txt"
while read -a line && (( ${#line[@]} )) # while can read a row
do username="${line[0]}"                # assign 1st to username
   email="${line[-1]//[<>]/}"           # last to email w/o <>
   name="${line[@]:2:$(( ${#line[@]} - 3 ))}" # all between to name
   echo "username:[$username] name=[$name] email=[$email]"
done < "$input"
```

Comment: That answer is even better :) - as is solve my problem completely, prev answer for 'one liner' is good for testing, where this one solve problem with variable assignment in bash.

Comment: be careful - it breaks if there are no spaces around the equals.

Comment: I upgraded the assignment to `email` to one line

Comment: Thanks Paul, this file is made by myself, as is part of svn -> git conversion, and i need to create usernames in git/kallithea, so im 100% sure that will be a space on equal char as file is created by other script ;)

Comment: Perfect. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

In bash as 'one liner' - we can use @dvo aswer:
`echo "username              = User Name       <u.name@domain.com>" | perl -lane 'while (/([^\s]+)\s+\=\s(\w+ \w+)\s+<([^>]+)>/g) {print $1}'`
Where:
$1, can be as group number in this case $1 username
$2 name with space
$3 as email.